# Eagle - Create THT package with copper only on bottom

Tags: eaglecad, pins

In Eagle 8.2.1 I want to create a package for a THT part. I only want to have copper on the bottom layer around the hole. I don't want copper on the top layer and I don't want the inside of the hole to be plated.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: That’s a good way to rip off the pad. Make the holes bigger and use PTH

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't care. No, I won't.